# return DB values on drop down list and exclude duplicates rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to include a drop down list on my web page but I don't like the idea of values of `<select>` tag being hardcoded since I have db, instead how can I retrieve the values of the DB and display it to a drop down list. Also, excluding the duplicates, for example:

Bryan

Bryan

Cindy

Mel

Cindy

So far, I have this:

```
<%=select_tag("Model[Name]", options_from_collection_for_select(Model.select(:Name).distinct,'Name', 'ID'),{prompt: 'Select'})%>
```

but It is only displaying a blank drop down list.

TYIA!

Comment: Are you using simpleform or standard Rails form_for?  Paste the whole form view as well as what fields you'll want shown from the Model.

Comment: You can use `.uniq` https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq for removing duplicates from the array that you pass to `select_tag`

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax what is the difference of .uniq vs .distinct when it comes to eliminating duplicates?